Best Practices for Form Rendering Fields in Django Forms
I'm looking to optimize the rendering of form fields in a Django ModelForm and ensure adherence to best practices. Currently, I've implemented a method as_custom_div within my ModelForm class to customize the rendering of form fields. Here's the method I've defined:
def as_custom_div(self):
    output = ''
    for field in self:
        output += f'<div class="input-container">{field}</div>'
    return output

In my template, I'm using this method to render the form fields:
<form action="">
    {{form.as_custom_div|safe}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

While this approach works, I'm curious if there's a more efficient or conventional way to achieve the same result. I want to ensure that I'm following best practices for rendering form fields in Django. Any insights or alternative approaches would be appreciated. Thank you!"

Django is not really made to get the last cycle out of a CPU. The idea of Python is that programmers convenience is more important than performance because programmers tend to be more expensive than adding some server capacity. In other words, by making Python (and Django) simply easier to use, you sacrifice a bit of performance, but the bonus is that you get there faster.


I'm looking to optimize the rendering of form fields in a Django ModelForm and ensure adherence to best practices.

The idea of Python (and Django) is that programmer convenience is often more important than processing time: typically it costs more to hire a few extra programmers, than to buy a bit more server capacity or add an extra machine. Python is not made to spent every cycle of the CPU in the absolute best way, but to try to implement something as fast and easy as possible. So you sacrifice a bit of performance to reduce costs to build it.
What is important is that the time complexity is under control, so limit the time complexity of algorithms, and limit the number of database queries, HTTP requests, file operations, etc. which usually take a lot more time than the program itself.
Django has a RenderableFormMixin [GitHub] that defines the different rendering modes:

class RenderableFormMixin(RenderableMixin):
    def as_p(self):
        """Render as <p> elements."""
        return self.render(self.template_name_p)

    def as_table(self):
        """Render as <tr> elements excluding the surrounding <table> tag."""
        return self.render(self.template_name_table)

    def as_ul(self):
        """Render as <li> elements excluding the surrounding <ul> tag."""
        return self.render(self.template_name_ul)

    def as_div(self):
        """Render as <div> elements."""
        return self.render(self.template_name_div)


It thus works with certain templates to render the entire form, for example with the django/forms/templates/django/forms/p.html template [GitHub]:

{{ errors }}
{% if errors and not fields %}
  <p>{% for field in hidden_fields %}{{ field }}{% endfor %}</p>
{% endif %}
{% for field, errors in fields %}
  {{ errors }}
  <p{% with classes=field.css_classes %}{% if classes %} class="{{ classes }}"{% endif %}{% endwith %}>
    {% if field.label %}{{ field.label_tag }}{% endif %}
    {{ field }}
    {% if field.help_text %}
      <span class="helptext"{% if field.auto_id %} id="{{ field.auto_id }}_helptext"{% endif %}>{{ field.help_text|safe }}</span>
    {% endif %}
    {% if forloop.last %}
      {% for field in hidden_fields %}{{ field }}{% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </p>
{% endfor %}
{% if not fields and not errors %}
  {% for field in hidden_fields %}{{ field }}{% endfor %}
{% endif %}


It is thus a lot more complicated since there are hidden fields, errors, helptext, etc. It is threfore quite cumbersome to get it good. This template for example does not include the media of the form, so we need to do this manually, it therefore might be better that this was included in the template.
But by using a template, one can also customize how the forms are rendered. Indeed, you could define a django/forms/p.html in the template directory in one of your apps to override how Django will render the form if you use .as_p(), it thus makes it more flexible how to render a form.
